# Build OpenCV with OpenCL Enabled and ON

Tags: opencv, opencl

I'm trying to run simple code with OpenCL enabled on OpenCV.

I've read the intro to OCL documentation and, as instructed, I built opencv with this flag: WITH_OPENCL=ON.

I did this by doing cmake -DWITH_OPENCL=ON and then built opencv on Mac (OS X Yosemite).

I then tried to run my code, but, according to my code, haveOpenCL() is false.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>

using namespace std;

int  main ()
{
        cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);
        cout << cv::ocl::haveOpenCL() << endl;
        if  ( ! cv::ocl::haveOpenCL ())
        {
                cout  <<  "OpenCL IS not avaiable ..."  <<  endl ;
                return 0;
        }
```

Does anybody know how to get OpenCV-OpenCL up and running?

**UPDATE:**

I checked my cvconfig.h file in opencv/build and this is what it says about OpenCL:
    /* OpenCL Support */
    /* #undef HAVE_OPENCL */
    /* #undef HAVE_OPENCL_STATIC */
    /* #undef HAVE_OPENCL_SVM */

I'm assuming that if OpenCL is really enabled, then the second line should be something like
    #define HAVE_OPENCL 1

This is auto-generated, so how can I fix this so that HAVE_OPENCL is 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is how I installed OpenCV 3.0 and that is also how I checked that it was working.  Checking the documentation here : **http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html**

**To correctly run the OCL module, you need to have the OpenCL runtime provided by the device vendor, typically the device driver.**

**To enable OCL support, configure OpenCV using CMake with WITH_OPENCL=ON. When the flag is set and if OpenCL SDK is installed, the full-featured OpenCV OCL module is built. Otherwise, the module may be not built.**

So I would try to make sure you have GPU that supports it and then make sure you have the drivers (SDK?)  I actually did some work with OpenCL first before installing OpenCV to make sure I had some understanding of how they worked independently.

Comment: can you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395439/build-opencv-with-opencl-support) Question