# OpenCV dnn, OpenCL and Nvidia graphic cards

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, opencl, nvidia

I have written a program using `dnn darknet` for *YOLO* object detection. Without setting any special flags, I simply do `net = dnn::readNetFromDarknet(xxx)` and do predictions which works fine using the CPU

I have a **GeForce GTX 1070** and now I want to use it to optimize the detection time. But when I try to set `DNN_TARGET_OPENCL` for my `net`, it says

```
OpenCV(ocl4dnn): consider to specify kernel configuration cache directory 
                 via OPENCV_OCL4DNN_CONFIG_PATH parameter.
OpenCL program build log: dnn/dummy
Status -11: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
-cl-no-subgroup-ifp
```

And it takes the same amount of time to process an image so I'm guessing *OpenCL* is not being used.

I am using `OpenCV 4.1.1` compiled with `WITH_CUDA=ON`. I have  `cuDNN` set up as well.

1. What is the connection between *OpenCL* and `dnn`?
2. How do I get my *YOLO* to use the graphic card and speed up the process?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257688/build-opencv-with-opencl-enabled-and-on but probably opencl will be slower than alexeyAB darknet yolo build with cuda for example. Afaik, opencv isnt planning a cuda / cuDNN / tensorRT backend.

Comment: Thanks. If openCV is not having a cuda backend, what is the purpose of `WITH_CUDA=ON`

Comment: opencv has cuda for sone traditional computer vision algorithms. However someone atm in fact IS working on a nvidua dnn backend. But not sure when it will br finished. Didnt know that before googling.

Comment: So basically `WITH_CUDA=ON` does nothing in my case I guess. Thanks. Can you please provide the source of that *nvidia dnn* news? I tried googling but couldn't find it

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14827

Comment: You can clone and build the PR branch to make use of the CUDA backend. It was rebased with the master just a few days ago. There won't be considerable changes happening before it gets merged. So code that works with the PR should also work after it's merged. [Video of the CUDA backend running YOLO v3 at ~60FPS](https://youtu.be/ljCfluWYymM?t=32)

Comment: [OpenCL backend on NVIDIA GPUs is generally slower than the CPU or Integrated Graphics](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14827#issuecomment-522229894). There is a possible explanation [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14827#issuecomment-523301246).

Comment: @Yashas appreciate your work. Didn't know it existed until now. Thanks!